# Visual Studio 2017's Projects folder has the project name folder and its sln file, but why are these not in its regular project folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm wondering if the setting got changed somehow. I'm not sure how to fix this.

In

> Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects

there is the Project name folder and its `.sln` file. If I create a second project, this starts getting messy. On top of that, while compiling, the `Debug/x64` folder is created and is placed in

> Visual Studio 2017\Projects folder

Shouldn't there be a folder like this...

> Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\My Project

which contains

> \My Project folder\
>
> \My Project.sln
>
> \Debug\

...

Comment: did you check "Create Directory for solution" when you create new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check **Create Directory for solution** when you create new project?
[image]